# Is there any MySQL regex pattern which can ignore numbers ie

Tags: mysql

Is there any MySQL regex pattern which can ignore numbers ie.

```
10, MI ROAD, JAIPUR, 302002
101, MD ROAD, JAIPUR, 302032
180, SIRSI ROAD, JAIPUR, 302012
```

10, 101, 180, Numbers and can search alphabetically by name

```
ORDER BY column NOT REGEXP '^[^0-9 ]+$' ASC
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore" numbers here?

Comment: My mean, it should search from the string "MI ROAD" not from 10, 101, 180 etc.

Comment: What is the search or intended query?